# viewpagerindicator fragment load when just clicked or swiped , not load all fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator

I use viewpagerindicator and have 6 fragment with custom listview from server. At startup this activity looks all fragment is loading. 
I want when a fragment startup just opened, clicked or swiped and do the loading.
And a fragment that has not been opened will be loading when opened, click or swipe later. how it?

this my code adapter viewpager

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class ViewAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private Context _context;
    String[] page_titles;

    public ViewAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, String[] page_title){
        super(fm);
        _context = context;
        this.page_titles = page_title;
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Fragment f = new Fragment();

        switch(position){
        case 0:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;

        case 1:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 2:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
             case 3:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 4:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
                    case 5:
            f = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        }

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return page_titles.length;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return page_titles[position];
    }



}
```

i has set

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); 
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

but if i swipe from fragment 0 to fragment index 1 and back swipe to index 0, or other index,  is always reload content, i want to make if back swipe to previous fragment not reload again ? how it

thanks... sorry for my english ..

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of fragments in adapter constructor and just return already created fragment from getItem

```
   Fragment[] f=new Fragment[6];

   public ViewAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, String[] page_title){
        super(fm);
        _context = context;
        this.page_titles = page_title;

            f[0] = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            f[1] = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            f[2] = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            f[3] = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            f[4] = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);
            f[5] = ContentActivity.newInstance(_context);

    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return f[position];
    }
```

Comment: if you do it this way you don't need to set this

Comment: i tried your solution, but it's seem not work, if i back or next fragment always reload... :(